# IntelliJ IDEA autoformat Line break after public/private

Tags: intellij-idea, autoformatting

For some weird reason when I autoformatted my project with some new settings in the autoformat it did things like this:

```
public
Object[] name(args){
```

I would rather like to have that in one line, how can I do that?

Comment: Change cody style settings?

Comment: Yes, but what setting does that. My post should clarify that I know where to find the code style settings, since I already altered them.

Comment: What about other fields, how are they auto-formatted?

Comment: What does have that to do with my question?

Comment: As you'll see in my answer below, the field you gave as an example is an array and has a dedicated section, and most likely if you define one as a local variable in a method it will also get formatted like that. I wanted to figure out whether it's just the arrays or something else as well. Also you can use @user when replying to someone, so they get notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, it's the wrapping under `Code style` => `Java` => `Wraping and Braces` => `Array initializer`, and you probably have the `New line after "{"` checked as well:

[image: Array initializer]